# PHP5 - initiating a class via string - 2 different ways

Tags: php, string, class, oop, static

As I am learning how PHP OOP works, I stumbled upon the following confusion.

```
class Foo {

    static function baz() {
        echo 'works';
    }

}

# 1
$a = 'Foo';
$a::baz();

# 2
Foo::baz();
```

PHP manual states that since 5.3.0, it is possible to reference a static class via a string (http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

What I don't understand is, what is the different between #1 and #2? Aren't they technically the same since both are calling a static function without initiating a class? Where can #1 be applied in practical scenario?

Comment: There is no difference. And it's not OOP. #1 in real life may be used in a badly designed system when one uses a variable to store a class name + a static method instead of polymorphism.

Comment: Why this is not OOP? Isn't use of class is a part of encapsulation (which is one of characteristics of OOP)?

Comment: you use a class as a namespace for a function. You can encapsulate with pure functions. And there is no even a single object in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is in a version. Before PHP5.3 you cannot use static methods with variable.

Also, second one 'hide' using of a class. Your IDE could not find class usage.

Also you could use object to call static methods.

```
class Foo {
    static function baz() {
        echo 'works';
    }
}

eval(
'$a = "Foo";
$a::baz();');

eval(
'$a = new Foo();
$a::baz();');

eval(
'Foo::baz();');
```

http://3v4l.org/WOK44

Comment: Do you mean 1st one is hidden? Because using Netbeans 8, I can find method using #2 but not #1.

Comment: @AlexanderK., yes, the first one. Missed.